# Finding out the transer function where the equation of the input function and the output function are given

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, applications

$G(s):=$The transfer function which I want to find out.

$f(t):=$The input function of some system.

$x(t):=$The output function of some system.

The below equation being given.

$4\frac{dx(t)}{dt}+3x(t)=2\int_{0}^{t}f(t)dt$

$4x'+3x=2\int_{0}^{t}f(t)dt$

I have no idea what should I do for next.

Can anyone tell me what should I refer or the solution for this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just consult the table and write down the Laplace transform term-by-term (assuming $x(t)=0$ for $t\le 0$)
$$
4sX(s)+3X(s)=\frac{2F(s)}{s}.
$$
Then apply that $X(s)=G(s)F(s)$.